# Python Requests Removing __ (Double Underscore) From URL

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm using Python requests to send a GET request. The GET request parameters have variables that contain double underscores. For example:

```
example.com/index.php?__action=login&__location=hub
```

But, when using `requests.get()` and checking the url used it completely strips off the variables that contain double underscores. Here's my example:

```
jsonData = json.dumps({
    'foo': 'bar'
})

params = {
    'data': urllib.quote_plus(jsonData),
    '__action': 'login',
    '__location': 'hub'
}

url = 'http://example.com/p/'
resp = request.get(url, params=params)

print resp.url
```

The URL isn't sending correctly, it's missing the params that contain double underscores.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Include real code you've actually ran and the real output from that code, please. Do not make any changes between the code you run and the code you post, and make sure the output you post is real output for that code.

Comment: Your code run perfectly fine, except you need to use `requests.get`, not `request.get`. Response is `http://example.com/p/?__action=login&data=%257B%2522foo%2522%253A%2522bar%2522%257D&__location=hub`

Comment: What makes you think it's being sent without the underscore parama?

Comment: Because when I print `requests.url` the URL is missing the params with underscores, but the `data` param is there. If I remove the underscores, the params are visible.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It was in fact not showing the params in the URL (thought I was going mad). The problem wasn't so obvious though.

`resp.url` was showing the URL after the page had redirected. It was redirecting because I wasn't using `https` and the server only responded to `https` requests. A typo that caused so many headaches.

`allow_redirects=False` shown me that `requests` wasn't removing anything.